# Show a list of data with corresponding images by fetching remote images from Cloudinary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, fetch, cloudinary

First of all, I understand this may be a low-level question to some of you but I believe the responses here will be a very good basic guidance for beginners like me, who wants to learn how to retrieve/fetch images.

I just want to know how exactly things work to get corresponding images for a typical website using ASP.NET MVC. To be precise, my website contains hundreds of restaurants, each restaurants having different sets of menu. I am not sure how does it work to get the corresponding menu images for particular restaurants.

I am thinking to store my images on cloud using Cloudinary. In Cloudinary, I would create separate folders for each restaurant, say like for thumbnail purpose, I create a folder named `Thumbnails`, in `Thumbnails` have hundreds of restaurants

- a folder named `KFC` that contains 2 photos `kfc-thumbnail-1` & `kfc-thumbnail-2`
- a folder named `Manhattan Fish Market` contains `mfm-thumbnail-1` & `mfm-thumbnail-2`

What I want to achieve is to show a list of restaurants with correspond thumbnails. FYI, each restaurant is assigned with a unique ID & name.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudinary, the path (i.e., `Thumbnails/KFC/..`) is represented in the image's `public_id`.

For example, `kfc-thumbnail-1`'s `public_id` will be - 
'Thumbnails/KFC/kfc-thumbnail-1`.

So, you can create a sub-folder for each restaurant under the `Thumbnails` folder and then use the [Admin API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#list_resources) to list all resources that have the `prefix` "Thumbnails". It will return all the restaurants' images that are inside this folder (In .NET you can use the `ListResourcesByPrefix` method).

Alternatively, you can use a `tag` for each restaurant and then [list all resources with a specific tag](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#list_resources_by_tag).
For more information on tags - 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#tagging_images

You can find Cloudinary's .NET repo - [here](https://github.com/cloudinary/CloudinaryDotNet).